# How to expand folder structure including symbolic links into real files and folders (no links) in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, symlink

I feel like there must be an elegant approach to this, so I'm asking all you clever people before I go hacking a complicated implementation together to do it.  :)  Thanks in advance for any ideas!

I'm using PowerShell.  On my local machine, there's a folder structure which includes some symbolic links.  I would like to replace those symbolic links with the real content they point to, so that I have all the folder structure and files without any links.  Bonus points if I can do this in place (without creating a new linkless copy).

I know that I can do almost what I want by simply copy/pasting a folder in Windows Explorer.  I want to get that done programmatically in PowerShell, preferably without creating a new folder that I have to then swap with the original before deleting the original.

Any tips?  :)

Comment: This was a interesting case but, remember you must send to us some of your code to fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the solution!

You can use this code:

```
$File_LST = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\example
foreach ($File in $File_LST) {
    if($File.Attributes -like "*ReparsePoint*"){
         $FIL_PAT =  $file.Target
         $FIL_DST = $File.Directory.FullName
         Remove-item $File.FullName -Force
         Copy-Item -Path $FIL_PAT -Destination $FIL_DST -Force
    }
}
```

I already test on my computers and works. When the file it's a symbolic link, the attribute of the destination its "*ReparsePoint*" and you need save the information on variables because when you delete the link, PowerShell lost the information.